# Get the month name using html date control

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, spservices, jsom, html5

1. I am using HTML controls to get interact with SharePoint 2013 list And performing CRUD operations using JSOM between forms and lists
2. My form is having HTML date control.And on the submission of
   it, the form need to fetch the month name.

Can any one help me how can I get the month name using HTML date control?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to get month.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
```

You can assign the value to `var d` from the HTML date control's output (like `var d = inputdateObject.value`)

Please note that month number starts from 0 like 0=January, 1=February etc.
Than after you can replace the month as per the number in your output.

Comment: Thanks for your support.The below written code is not going fine with IE browser .Can any one help me

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="date" id="myDate" >
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
alert(x);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: input elements with type="date" are not supported in Internet Explorer or Firefox

Comment: You can check all control's compatibility here ...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets